# How to remove HTML element using its class value in Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following HTML element ;
`<a class="addAnother">Add Another</a>`

I want to remove from the page, using Jquery.

Comment: I will have to downvote it. you should have done homework or at least Googled!

Comment: apparently they aren't ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('a').removeClass("addAnother");
```

If you are asking how to remove element:

```
$('.addAnother').remove();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.addAnother').each(function(){
    this.remove();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use jquery's [`.remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) function, before that select that element by using the [`class selector`](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/),

```
$('.addAnother').remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use **[.remove()](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)**.

> Remove the set of matched elements from the DOM.

```
$('.svg_selector').remove();
```

if you have other elements with same class and to target anchor only:

```
$('a.svg_selector').remove();
```